# Function in function argument in C

Tags: c

I write this code but i recieve error. How can I implement a function in a function parameter?

I want to make this:

```
A function that manipulates input file according to its function pointer parameter.
The function should print the manipulated file content to the console. You have to
implement following function pointers;
a. void uppercase(char content[]); //converts all letters to
uppercase
b. void lowercase(char content[]); // converts all letters
to lowercase
c. void capitalize(char content[]); //capitalizes each word
d. void toggle(char content[]); // converts lowercase
letters to uppercase and uppercase letters to lowercase
```

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void text_file_manipulator( char str_filename[],int (*pf_convertion)( char content[]);


int main(void)
{

    int hour, minute, d_hour, d_minute, d_size, inc;
    double a, b, c, search_starting_point,step_size;

    puts("-------------------------------");
    printf("text_file_manipulator:\n");
    text_file_manipulator("in.txt", pf_convertion("uppercase"));
    text_file_manipulator("in.txt", pf_convertion("lowercase"));
    text_file_manipulator("in.txt", pf_convertion("capitalize"));
    text_file_manipulator("in.txt", pf_convertion("toggle"));
    puts("-------------------------------");
}
void text_file_manipulator( char str_filename[],int (*pf_convertion)( char content[])){

}

int pf_convertion( char content[]){

}
```

Error message when I compile:

```
1.c: In function ‘main’:
1.c:14:2: error: passing argument 2 of ‘text_file_manipulator’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
  text_file_manipulator("in.txt", pf_convertion("uppercase"));
  ^
1.c:3:6: note: expected ‘int (*)(char *)’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 void text_file_manipulator( char str_filename[],int (*pf_convertion)( char content[]));
      ^

1.c:15:2: error: passing argument 2 of ‘text_file_manipulator’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
  text_file_manipulator("in.txt", pf_convertion("lowercase"));
  ^
1.c:3:6: note: expected ‘int (*)(char *)’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 void text_file_manipulator( char str_filename[],int (*pf_convertion)( char content[]));
      ^

1.c:16:2: error: passing argument 2 of ‘text_file_manipulator’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
  text_file_manipulator("in.txt", pf_convertion("capitalize"));
  ^
1.c:3:6: note: expected ‘int (*)(char *)’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 void text_file_manipulator( char str_filename[],int (*pf_convertion)( char content[]));
      ^
```

1.c:17:2: error: passing argument 2 of ‘text_file_manipulator’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
  text_file_manipulator("in.txt", pf_convertion("toggle"));
  ^
1.c:3:6: note: expected ‘int (*)(char *)’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 void text_file_manipulator( char str_filename[],int (*pf_convertion)( char content[]));
      ^

Comment: Additionally, it would be expected that you **think about** the code that you write.

Comment: `text_file_manipulator("in.txt", pf_convertion("uppercase"));` --> `text_file_manipulator("in.txt", uppercase);` Also return type is different with `int` and `void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides some other compilation errors, the main semantic error here is that this doesn't make sense:

```
text_file_manipulator("in.txt", pf_convertion("uppercase"));
```

You are calling pf_convertion with argument "uppercase", which will return an int. And then, you're trying to pass this int to the second argument of `text_file_manipulator`, which is supposed to be a function.

What you wanted to do is probably just

```
text_file_manipulator("in.txt", pf_convertion);
```

EDIT:

So you need to implement the functions you mentioned (uppercase, etc.) with the correct signatures, and do the calls like this:

```
text_file_manipulator("in.txt", uppercase);
text_file_manipulator("in.txt", lowercase);
text_file_manipulator("in.txt", capitalize);
text_file_manipulator("in.txt", toggle);
```

Comment: No, what the OP wants is probably: `text_file_manipulator("in.txt", pf_convert_uppercase);`, but then s/he'll have to write the `pf_convert_uppercase()` function. The `pf_convertion()` is useless!